# Problems with a Sharp Architecture HasOne relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, one-to-one

I'm building a direct port of the ASP.NET Membership Provider from SQL to Sharp Arch 1.9.6 (using Fluent NHibernate).  The issue comes up when trying to create the one-to-one relationship between the aspnet_Users and the aspnet_Membership table.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class User : EntityWithTypeId<Guid>
{
    public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }
}

public class Membership : EntityWithTypeId<Guid>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : IAutoMappingOverride<User>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<User> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("aspnet_Users");
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.Membership)
            .PropertyRef(r => r.User)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class MembershipMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Membership>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Membership> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("aspnet_Membership");

        mapping.Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("UserId")
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("User");
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.User)
            .ForeignKey("Membership_User_FK_Manual")
            .Constrained();
    }
}
```

The rest of the properties are all configured but to keep the post as short as possible I've only listed the necessary information.

The unit test from Sharp Arch that generates the DB schema does so correctly showing the one-to-one mapping between the tables.

The issue is when I go to retrieve the user from the database using the Repository that Sharp Arch provides.  I get an error:

```
NHibernate.PropertyAccessException : Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of TrackerI9.Core.Providers.Entities.Membership
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid.
```

I'm using SQLite as my DB for testing and from the INSERT statements that get output to the test console I have verified that the data is being inserted into the DB correctly and using the appropriate IDs.  I can include them and the stack trace if necessary.

I've been working on this for a week now and haven't found any solution.  I could always join the two tables into one and just move on but as I said above I'd prefer to do a DIRECT port.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: As things turn out, one of the conventions that were being used for the Enums were causing the invalid cast exception.  Once that was removed everything worked like expected.